# How to synchronise and and update denormalised cassandra table

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, nosql

I stumbled upon a problem while working on a spring application with cassandra.
By practice Cassandra encourage Query by design when you're designing your data model and one blocker that's been bugging me is what happen when one of the table updates it's value and it just so happen that particular value is a primary key on another table?

See photo below
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USkyK.png)

[image]

In the photo if we update the users email to another value I typically do a save in Spring cassandra however when doing batch operation it instead add a new entry in the user_by_email table because of the new partition key.

What are your typical solution towards this kind of problem? I thought about querying the old email first then do a delete on user_by_email table however that just sound inefficient to me.

Answer (score 0):

To keep denormalised tables in sync, you will need to use CQL `BATCH` statements. It will group inserts, updates and deletes into one atomic transaction. Have a look at this article where I've explained it in a bit more detail -- https://community.datastax.com/articles/2744/.

For example, if you had these tables to maintain:

- `movies`
- `movies_by_actor`
- `movies_by_genre`

then you would group the updates in a CQL `BATCH` like this:

```
BEGIN BATCH
  INSERT INTO movies (...) VALUES (...);
  INSERT INTO movies_by_actor (...) VALUES (...);
  INSERT INTO movies_by_genre (...) VALUES (...);
APPLY BATCH;
```

Note that it is also possible to do `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements as well as conditional writes in a batch.

The above example is just to illustrate it in cqlsh and is not used in reality. Here is an example `BatchStatement` using the Java driver:

```
SimpleStatement insertMovies =
  SimpleStatement.newInstance(
    "INSERT INTO movies (...) VALUES (?, ...)", <some_values>);

SimpleStatement insertMoviesByActor =
  SimpleStatement.newInstance(
    "INSERT INTO movies_by_actor (...) VALUES (?, ...)", <some_values>);

SimpleStatement insertMoviesByGenre =
  SimpleStatement.newInstance(
    "INSERT INTO movies_by_genre (...) VALUES (?, ...)", <some_values>);

BatchStatement batch =
  BatchStatement.builder(DefaultBatchType.LOGGED)
    .addStatement(insertMovies)
    .addStatement(insertMoviesByActor)
    .addStatement(insertMoviesByGenre)
    .build();
```

For details, see [Java driver Batch statements](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/statements/batch/). Cheers!

Comment: I have some pretty good idea with batch operation however my problem at the moment is trying to update the User table email and since my table is denomalized I also have user_by_email table. If I were to update the email on the User table then when doing a save in the batch operation for user_by_email it will instead insert a new entry rather than updating the old entry in the user_by_email because the email is a new value

Comment: The idea is the same. But instead of just 2 `INSERT`s for the 2 tables, you'd also have a `DELETE` for the `user_by_email` table included in the batch. Cheers!

Comment: I see. That sounds heavy seeing I have to do a read to retrieve the old email value for deletion before every save operation.